# Visual Studio Online ASP.Net Website build with global resources

Tags: asp.net, msbuild, azure-devops, vs-web-site-project

We have a ASP.Net website (not a web "application") project and we are using Visual Studio Online TFS as our source control. Our website uses resource files (.resx) located in App_GlobalResources to store strings used in the UI.

The problem is when we use daily or ad-hoc builds from visual studio online to deploy the website, the pages which use string resources in the UI errors out. But we can visit the pages which does not use any string resource. I understand that when building, aspnet compiler compiles the resource files into App_GlobalResources.dll. I can see that dll in the bin. But the pages depending on resources don't work.

We don't see this problem if we use Visual Studio (2013) "Publish Website" command. This only happens when we use a build generated by VSO for our deployment.

Does anybody have an idea why this can occur?

Comment: You should migrate to a web application. Web sites are deprecated technology and a bad practice to use.

Comment: I kind of agree with you. Upgrading to a Web Application is also in our pipeline. But I wouldn't call Web Site as deprecated as even Visual Studio 2013 has "File -> New -> Web Site" option.

Comment: It has the feature as MSFT commits to supporting things for 10 years. However there has been no investment in that model since 2005 and I do not believe that is will be part of Dev14 (.vNext)